# Flexbox vertical center first item fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

I got a div that contains an FontAwesome icon and a short text.

```css
.box{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <i>Icon</i>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

As the text reaches a certain length, it goes to the next line and the icon moves a bit up that everything's centered.

When I have more than one of these .box divs, side by side, I want the **icons to stay aligned with each other, no matter how long the text below gets**.

Comment: Can you show a drawing of the desired outcome?

Comment: Basically there are 3 boxes, each box has an icon and a text - they are centered in the box.

In one box there is a bit more text, so the icon moves up that the content is centered. But i want the icons in all 3 boxes match the same height, as they are in a grid and aligned aside each other.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box > i {
    min-height: 30px;
}
.box > p {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: when doing it like this the text is beside the icon, not below

Comment: Then give .box flex-direction: column

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just using a min-height on the text.